# QGIS: How to find the shortest distance between two line layers

Tags: qgis

I am working with two layers in QGIS, which are both line layers. Essentially, I would like to add an attribute in one layer indicating the shortest distance to a feature in the other layer, as well as that other feature's ID. Is there a tool to do this without converting one of the two layers to points first? Or some relatively simple python process?

For example, I have a river segments layer and a road segments layer. I would like to add the distance to the nearest road & the name of that road to the river layer.